# Как правильно подключить json во Vue.js и использовать его в компонентах?

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js

Пишу магазин на Laravel и корзину покупателя на Vue.js. Есть json со всеми товарами, который формируется админом при добавлении нового товара. Он лежит в js/products.json. Как мне подключить правильно этот json во Vue.js и использовать его в компонентах?

Comment: Ваш локальный json ничем не отличается от ответа API в виде json'а. Вот почитайте, на оф. сайте есть примеры https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html

Comment: спасибо за ответ, искал в документации, а надо было еще заглянуть в Cookbook))